# How to find the lowest multiple of field A that is equal or bigger then field B

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm looking for a way to find the lowest multiple (including * 1) of PackingQuantity that is bigger or equal to OrdQty (see code below). Functionally, each ordered quantity must be a multiple of the item's packing quantity.

So,

If OrdQty = 3 and PackingQuantity = 5, OrdQty must become 5.

If OrdQty = 5 and PackingQuantity = 3, OrdQty must become 6.

Etc...

```
SELECT VmiItemUpdates.OrdQty, VmiItemPackagingQuantities.Quantity as PackingQuantity 
FROM vm.VmiItemUpdates 
INNER JOIN vm.VmiItemPackagingQuantities ON VmiItemUpdates.[itemcode] = VmiItemPackagingQuantities.[itemcode]
```

But I'm struggling to find a logic method on doing this in TSQL. Could someone give me a hint for an approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

find the ratio of `OrdQty / PackingQuantity` and use `CEILING()` to round up to nearest integer and multiply back with the PackingQuantity

```
NewOrdQty = CEILING(OrdQty * 1.0 / PackingQuantity) * PackingQuantity
```

Answer (score 0):

One method would be using a modulo to add the difference between the `PackingQuantity` and the modulo to the `Ordqty`.

For the value `5` for `OrdQty` and `3` for `PackingQuantity` you want the value `6`. The result of `OrdQty` Modulo `PackingQuantity` is `2` which you then subtract from `PackingQuantity` giving `1`, and finally add that to `OrdQty`, giving `6`:

```sql
SELECT OrdQty,
       PackingQuantity,
       OrdQty + PackingQuantity - ISNULL(NULLIF(OrdQty % PackingQuantity,0),PackingQuantity) AS RequiredOrdQty
FROM (VALUES(3,5),
            (5,3),
            (7,4),
            (3,10),
            (17,7))V(OrdQty,PackingQuantity)
```

The (yucky) `ISNULL`/`NULLIF`s are there as the value of `x % x` is `0` not `x`; if we didn't "swap" `0` to be `x`, then you would end up packing a whole extra quantity when the values round nicely.